# cannot load such file -- bootstrap/sass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am getting

```
cannot load such file -- bootstrap/sass
```

I have installed bootstrap-sass-2.0.3.1, sass-3.1.18, sass-rails-3.2.5, coffee-rails-3.2.2 and uglifier-1.2.4

Why would I be getting this error?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

put bootstrap-sass in the assets group of the Gemfile

```
group :assets do
    gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.5'
    gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.2'
    gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.2.4'
    gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.0.3.1'
end
```

Comment: Will these gems be available in the production environment?  I'm particularly wondering about the 'bootstap-sass' gem.

Answer (score 12):

I was being a bit ahead of myself, appears I hadn't run `gem install bootstrap-sass` yet...

Oops.