# Failed npm run dev Laravel with TailwindCSS

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css

I just follow instruction from https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/laravel but i cant connect the tailwind to laravel project

in cmd:

```
sh: cross-env: command not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/testing/.npm/_logs/2020-12-15T09_27_32_113Z-debug.log
```

resources/css/app.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

resources/views/welcome.blade.php

```
...
   <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
...
```

webpack.mix.js

```
mix.js("resources/js/app.js", "public/js").postCss(
    "resources/css/app.css",
    "public/css",
    [require("tailwindcss")]
);
```

package.json

```
  "devDependencies": {
        "@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat": "^2.0.2",
        "autoprefixer": "^9.8.6",
        "axios": "^0.19",
        "cross-env": "^7.0",
        "laravel-mix": "^5.0.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^7.0.35",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.0",
        "sass": "^1.15.2",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
        "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.0.2"
    },
```

Comment: `cross-env` is there in your dependencies. Did you run `npm install` after creating your project? Try running `npm install && npm run dev`

Comment: omg i forgot that command haha. Thanks a lot man @ScottBrown.

Comment: Haha no problem, we've all done something like that at some point (ahem... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10731246/cannot-load-such-file-bootstrap-sass/24024253#24024253)

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issue and I solved it with the below.

Reference Link: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation#post-css-7-compatibility-build

https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/2854

Run this command

> sudo npm uninstall tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer

Then this command

> sudo npm install tailwindcss@npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat postcss@^7
> autoprefixer@^9

Now run following commands

> sudo npm install

> sudo npm run dev